# Need help about ASP.net html code for my project i want to display data

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to display data when a user logged in to my website, it will display his/her only data that they added+ their user information in my sidebar, just see the picture.
Thanks for helping guys! 
Hope you understand me,
I'm currently using **VisualStudio 2010** because we are required to use it at the same time **MS SQL** but I have no problem with my database+ I'm not allowed to use `datasource` in designer my prof said I must do the code :)), just the code in this. Peace!
If you can't see the picture, you can click this: http://sdrv.ms/ZQyhxK

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please tell us what you already tried? Making the question more specific it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: i don't think you should specify '@' character for the parameter name in your parameters.add(...). if the pameter name is @UserID in your SQL statement, then you should write `parameters.add("UserID", ...).Value = "..."` in your code

Comment: Thanks for your concerns and help, I wanna try to upload my project so anyone can actually open my file :)) I'm not that good in explaining 'cause I'm still a newbie here.

I'm just wondering what is the difference between... next comment

Comment: con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserID, UserFN, UserLN, UserEmail, UserBDay, UserCarShopName, UserShopAdd FROM Users WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value 
            = lblUserID.Text;
        SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DlUsers.DataSource = data;
        DlUsers.DataBind();
        con.Close();

Comment: and this
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserID, UserFN, UserLN, UserEmail, UserBDay, UserCarShopName, UserShopAdd FROM Users WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value 
            = lblUserID.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "Users");
        DlUsers.DataSource = ds;
        DlUsers.DataBind();
        con.Close();

Comment: and addition to that, if I used any of those codes, my error is always this, see the link :) --> http://sdrv.ms/10QppKU sorry about sharing link with my skydrive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid",lbluserid.value)
```

You can also use:

```
SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[1];
p[0] = new SqlParameter("@userid",lbluserid.value);
```

Then

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```